# Is there anyway to easily move whole method blocks around in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a program with several methods, however, as I have added new methods, some of them are not in a logical order in their source code files.  I was wondering:

- Is there a way to easily reorder the functions in a file without having to highlight the whole method, and cut-and-paste it into the proper order?  For instance, is there some way to see all the methods in a list and just drag the items in the list into a new order?
- Is there a tool that will analyze my source code and automatically suggest what it thinks is the most logical order for my methods and then will reorder them for me?

I have done done some research on this and the only answer I can find is to use:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.vclinkertool.functionorder%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

But this tool uses a text document to put the methods in the desired order. Is there any easier way of doing this?

Comment: What is the right order?

Comment: The order in which the occur when debugging the program, obviously there are multiple way to run through it based on the programs variables etc. But I was meaning the general way the program runs through the functions.

Comment: How could this be determined at complie time? Are you looking for tool that performs a functional analysis of the code, writes a viable range of test cases and runs the cases, and then calculates the most common order in which functions are executed?

Comment: If you use StyleCop http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sourceanalysis/archive/2010/01/04/stylecop-for-visual-studio-2010.aspx it can impose a consistent order to your function declarations.

Comment: That is only for C# :/ is there an easy way of just moving around functions? rather than automated?

Comment: Could somebody please suggest why this question has been marked down? Ive made it clear what I'm looking for and I've done research beforehand. Im new to Stack overflow and any comments to help me improve the clarity of my questions is much appreciated.

Comment: So you're not looking for a tool that automatically determines the best order, nor corrects it for you, you are just looking for an easy way to drag and drop whole methods into the order that you want and have already determined?

Comment: Well I tool to automatically do it would have been great but after further research I cannot find any others other than the StyleCop which was for C# and wasn't sure if it was going to do it correctly. But yes an easier way to move them about was what I was looking for, it would be great if Visual Studio had a list of functions which you could move quickly and easily. thanks for the answer below

Comment: I don't know why people are down-voting this question either.  While it wasn't the best worded question, I think it's a valid question which is not outside the scope of SO.  I edited the question to be more clear and to the point.  Perhaps the down-voters will now reconsider their votes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are just looking for a simple way to cut and paste/drag whole methods in the code editor window, you can do so with the code outlining feature in visual studio.

1. Select the **Edit > Outlining > Collapse to Definitions** option in the menu.  This will cause all the methods and properties to be displayed as single lines in the editor window.
2. You can then easily see the order and cut and paste them into the correct order.  You can also use the mouse select the whole method line and drag it to a new location in the file.

I've never used ReSharper before, so I can't speak to the actual functionality, but upon searching the web real quick for a better solution than the source code outlining option, I found that ReSharper may support this using their "File Structure" dialog:

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/navigation_search.html#File_Structure

Comment: That I didn't know you could click and drag them I was cutting and pasting them when they had been collapsed.

Comment: That "File Structure" dialog is brilliant just what I was looking for. I might have to have a read up on some of the other functions this offers. Seem like a very useful piece of kit

Comment: @TeamGB Yes, I've never used it, but I've known and heard from many people who love ReSharper and can't imagine life without it.

Answer (score 22):

I am using Resharper for Visual Studio 2015, it moves entire methods up and down with a keyboard shortcut.

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + (<kbd>up-arrow</kbd> or <kbd>down-arrow</kbd>)

Comment: works with Visual Studio 2013/ReSharper 8.0.2 as well. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah it's also another product too, so not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

*Is there a tool that will analyze my source code and automatically suggest what it thinks is the most logical order for my methods and then will reorder them for me?*

There is nothing on the market that will do this for you.

For manual manipulation of code files, check out [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), which includes [keyboard shortcuts](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Keyboard_Shortcuts.html) to move methods, properties or fields up/down in the code file.

Comment: DevExpress CodeRush is good at this as well.  http://www.devexpress.com/Subscriptions/DXperience/coderush-features.xml

Comment: ReSharper gave extremely poor ide performance when using VB.NET for me so I got rid of it. Seems like it was developed for C# and Vb was an afterthought

Comment: ReSharper has this functionality. See nano2nd's answer.

Comment: I was referring to _Is there a tool that will analyze my source code and automatically suggest what it thinks is the most logical order for my methods and then will reorder them for me?_

Answer (score 1):

The [CodeMaid](https://www.codemaid.net/) extension for Visual Studio has a Reorganize Active Document feature that will move blocks of C# code around and add region tags following Microsoft’s StyleCop convention or your own preferences.